# combine like and filter_by method in sqlachemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
    keyword = request.form.get('keyword')  

    search ="%{}%".format(keyword)

    posts = Create.query.filter(Create.title.like(search)).all()
```

## I want to combine like and filter_by method

```
    users_created = Create.query.filter_by(author = session['username']).all()
```

Comment: What goes wrong with your current code?  What does your data look like?

Comment: How do I combine 2 methods Create.query.filter(Create.title.like(search)).all() and Create.query.filter_by(author = session['username']).all()        @Simon Crane

Comment: This question isn't particularly clear. Could you add some detail explaining what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.leeladharan.com/sqlalchemy-query-with-or-and-like-common-filters

You can chain calls to `filter` like this:

```py
posts = Create.query.filter(Create.title.like(search)).filter_by(author = session['username']).all()
```